# change UIViewController.h, report a lot of error

Tags: ios

I try to read some detail of UIViewController.h.
I change the code occasionally, but I recovery it immediately.
UIViewController.h has nothing change.

After I build run th project, it reported a lot of errors, all related to UIKit framework.

[image]

[[image]

[image]

I checked the file UIViewController.h on hard disk and found that the file date is Today.

I am sure my project(run well before) has nothing change, but it reported 22 errors now.

I try to use command line

```
touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm UIViewController.h
```

to change the file sate to the same date as others .h file.
but it looks like nothing improved.

Is there any person met the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, download Xcode again and overwrite the old xcode, everything is OK